# iOS14 Exchange Online shared mailbox

Tags: iphone, email, ipad, office365, ios14

Since upgrading to iOS14 on iPhones or iPads shared mailboxes accessed via IMAP on Exchange online have stopped working.

You get a very generic error,

> **Cannot Get Mail** The mail server "outlook.office365.com" is not responding. Verify that you have entered the correct account info in Mail settings."

Deleting the account in iOS14 and re-adding it results in error about SSL.

> **Cannot Connect Using SSL** Do you want to try setting up the account without SSL?

Eventually resulting in the following error message.

> **Cannot Get Mail** Logins are disabled for [insert description]

Using the IMAP method to access shared mailboxes is still working fine on other iOS13 devices.

I know Microsoft are planning on retiring basic authentication have they some rolled inline with an iOS update?

Details of the IMAP method to access shared Exchange online Mailboxes.

> ```
> Incoming Mail Server
> Hostname: outlook.office365.com
> Username: [your username]\[email address of shared mailbox]
> Password: [Your password]
>
> Outgoing Mail Server
> Hostname: smtp.office365.com
> Username: [your username]
> Password: [Your password]
> ```

Comment: Found a similar post on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/msp/comments/ivbinn/o365_exchange_online_email_with_shared_mailbox_on/

Answer (score 0):

My shared mailbox stopped on iOS on 17th September out of the blue. Now, November, I'm getting more and more reports from others (iOS14). Creating a login and password for the shared mailbox was my workaround.